# How to change and create multiple repositories in Visual Studio 2022 - 17.04

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution called `Finanzdurchblick_Solution`

Within that solution, I have a main project `Finanzdurchblick` and two referenced projects `Category_Helper_Project`, `CSV_Helper_Project` and an additional secondary, local project `String_Helper_Project`

When I go to the `git Changes` page, I can see that the `String_Helper_Project` is selected.
I could stage changes I make in `String_Helper_Project` but there are no unstaged changes. Changes in my Main Project `Finanzdurchblick` are not included:
[image]

When I open the `Git` dropdown at the top of visual studio, I can see the local repositories  for my referenced projects but my main poject `Finanzdurchblick` is not visible there:
[image]
[image]

How can I add a local repository for my main project? And how do I switch to it in the `Git Changes` window? I am used to see a button "Add repository" when there is no repository yet. From there I could choose to push to a remote location or keep it locally.

I have also checked out the `Create Git Repository` page but could not find how to create one there. Interestingly, it references my `String_Helper_Project` in the path there:
[image]

I already checked the solution folders and could not find any `.git` folders.

Edit: in my Solution explorer, I found that `String_Helper_Project` is "checked" in, when I hover the Mouse over the small blue Lock beneath it.

Comment: When i open `Create Git repository` dialog (by clicking ... menu in repos list in statusbar), it [looks differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGH3i.png). It lets me select local path and init a local repo in arbitrary folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Enable Repo Switching in Git Changes and other areas:

Visual studio 2022 adds the support for multiple git repositories in one solution.

This is still a preview feature. To enable the feature:

1. Press `Control` + `Q` to open the search function or use the searchbar at the top of visual studio.
2. type `features` and choose the search result which states `Environment > Preview Features`
   [image]
3. Enable `Enable Multi Repo Support (requires Solution to restart)`
   [image]
4. Restart your visual Studio

Now you should be able to switch between your Repositories In the `Git Explorer` and Git Branch Explorer:
[image]

### Add new Repositories

In order to Add new Repositories, go through the File Menu:
`File` > `New` > `Repository`

There you will find the Option to add a new (local) Repostitory.
[image]

Make sure to choose the proper path to your project.
[image]
This will also generate the gitignore files which are not included when creating the repo with an external application.

Comment: Multiple git repositories in one solution work for me even without turning on `Enable Multi Repo Support`. This option doesn't seem to add anything except for support for switching between repositories directly from Git windows. Previously i had to switch between them through menu.

Comment: eh then I dont know. At least it made my Life easier. You mentioned that you can add a repository through the Dialog ` ... menu in repos list in statusbar` does that apply for multiple repos in one solution?

Comment: Yes, repositories list may contain several entries in single solution and allows selecting active, Menu items makes it possible to init new repos or add existing to the list. And all this stuff works without enabling Enable Multi Repo Support. I should mention that i'm using release version of VS 17.0.5 https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR1Wf.png